# Ruby regexp throws invalid backref number/name error

Tags: ruby, regex

My current code is intended to go through an enormous .csv file and reformat certain dates to an SQL Datetime friendly format. They are currently DDMMYYYY, I want them as YYYYMMDD, and this is the approach I've taken (lifted from a different SO question):

```
CSV.foreach('file.csv') do |x|
if x[0] == "1"
    x.gsub(/([0-9]{2})-+([0-9]{2})-+([0-9]{4})/,/\3-\2-\1/)

else
end
```

This throws the error "invalid backref number/name".

Docs tell me I can avoid this by defining the groups with `?<name>` and backreferencing them with `\k<name>`, but all my attempts to do so have ended in failure. Could someone show me how it's supposed to look, or provide an alternate solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second parameter for the gsub should be a string, not a regex (see the [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-gsub)).

Do:

```
x.gsub(/([0-9]{2})-+([0-9]{2})-+([0-9]{4})/,'\3-\2-\1')
```

Note that the second parameter uses `'replacement string'` instead of `/replacement string/`.

Comment: Also, be careful to use a single-quoted string - "\3-\2-\1" will interpolate to unicode characters, and you'll get "\u0003-\u0002-\u0001"

Comment: Ugh. I feel so stupid. I spent hours trying to fix this. Anyway, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5):

No regex:

```
str = "DDMMYYYY"
p new_str = str[4..7] << str[2..3] << str[0..1]
#=> "YYYYMMDD"
```

Answer (score 3):

I think it's worth adding that while the above answers are correct they don't address the error that the OP was getting. This error is not an issue with the second parameter being a regular expression. In fact in the above case ruby never actually calls the gsub method as the regular expression in the second parameter won't parse. A backslash followed by any number will cause this error. It's an invalid regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

Use `'` to delimit your second `gsub` parameter (the replacement string), instead of `/`

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with [`Date::strptime`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-_strptime) and [`Date#strftime`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-strftime):

```
dates = %w[12122012 10121012 12032013]
#=> ["12122012", "10121012", "12032013"]

dates.each do |date_str|
  date = Date.strptime(date_str, '%d%m%Y')
  puts date.strftime('%Y %m %d')
end

# 2012 12 12
# 1012 12 10
# 2013 03 12
```